# Hide org-mode nodes with priorities below a threshold

Tags: org-mode

Is it possible to hide org-mode nodes with set priorities below a threshold?

My use case is:
I have a bunch of large org-mode files with lots of nodes in each of them, complex nested hierarchies and I would like to (temporarily) hide lower priorities nodes to make the rest more noticeable.

For example, a criterion like "priority below #C or [#5]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some caveats, you can use `org-match-sparse-tree` for such searches:

```
C-c /m PRIORITY<"C"
```

will create a sparse tree (see [Sparse Trees](https://orgmode.org/manual/Sparse-Trees.html) in the manual) of headlines with priority `A` or `B`, thereby hiding headlines with priority `C`.

The big caveat is the sense of the inequality: the matching expression compares strings (it doesn't know how to interpret them as priorities), so `"A"` and `"B"` are *less* than `"C"` as strings, even though they are greater as priorities.

The second caveat is the interpretation of the sparse tree, but that is just a matter of practice and squinting hard in order to convince yourself that it's doing the right thing.

The third is that I am using the standard values of [priorities](https://orgmode.org/manual/Priorities.html#index-priorities) with no customizations. If you are customizing them, you will need to tweak the expression accordingly.

The relevant references to the manual (in addition to the `Sparse Trees` reference above) are [Tag searches](https://orgmode.org/manual/Tag-Searches.html), which is really about searching using tags *and* properties; and [Matching tags and properties](https://orgmode.org/manual/Matching-tags-and-properties.html) which describes the syntax of the matching expressions.